# Using TinyMCE in plugin?

Tags: plugins, php, javascript, tinymce

I've successfully integrated [DataTables Editor](https://editor.datatables.net/) into WordPress as its own plugin. It loads successfully and I can edit a DataTables' table. What I'm trying to figure out is how to utilize WordPress' TinyMCE within DataTables Editor.

DataTables Editor has its own TinyMCE [plugin](https://editor.datatables.net/fields/plugins) that allows usage of TinyMCE within Editor. What has me confused... **is how can I load WordPress' own TinyMCE alongside DataTables Editor so I don't have to load an external copy of TinyMCE?**

This is the code I'm using to create the instance of DataTables Editor:

```
var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
    "ajaxUrl": "../dct-content/plugins/datatables-editor/php/table.qpidvulh_to-do_list.php",
    "domTable": "#qpidvulh_to-do_list",
    "fields": [
        {
            "label": "Item",
            "name": "item",
            "type": "tinymce",
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the solution is to search through the Editor javascript code, and see how it handles the "tinymce" value in the fields array. Then just to change all links to the existing TinyMCE installation.

Comment: This is all I could find: "tinymce": function () {return conf._editor;}

Comment: Then the next thing to my opinion would be to check the conf object wherever it is (if it isn't in minified or obfuscated code)